# `firebase_tools.firestore .delete` requires a token, but where does that token come from?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud (callable) function which deletes a firestore document and all child entities, including sub-collections. I'm doing this by slightly modifying the function provided my firebase in their docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

The important bit is here:

```js
...
return firebase_tools.firestore
      .delete(path, {
        project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
        recursive: true,
        yes: true,
        token: functions.config().fb.token
      })
...
```

When I call this function from my webpage (after a user has anthenticated), the web client throws an error that the remote function caused an error. In the firebase console, I find this error:

`Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`

This is pointing to the line in the above code snippet: `token: functions.config().fb.token`. So `.fb` is null.

What is going on here?

Searching the web tells me something about `login:ci` at the command line, but although I'm developing this on my laptop, when the app is deployed, *there will be no command line*. The website will be on firebase hosting. It makes a call to a firebase cloud function. I'm using firebase auth for user authentication (email/password) and storing data in firestore.

Further, I'm already enabled on my command line, since I can do `firebase deploy --only functions` just fine. How do I make sure `functions.config().fb` doesn't return a null??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want, you can just paste the token string directly into the code, replacing `functions.config().fb.token`.  The authors of that page probably figured you didn't want to do that, so they suggested you should create a configuration item for it instead.

If you don't want to paste it in, and you actually want to configure the function to get that value from [configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), you will have to set the config on the command line using [functions:config:set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#functions-commands) like this:

```
firebase functions:config:set fb.token=<YOUR-TOKEN>
```

The deploy your function again so it can use that value.

If you found the documentation confusing, I suggest using the "send feedback" link at the top right of the page.

Comment: Where do I get this token from? Does it remain the same for the life of the project and, if not, when and how often do I have to generate this token? If space allows, _what_ is this token for? I've been able to use auth, firestore, functions, so far, without needing this token.

Comment: The instructions are in a comment in the code of the documentation you linked. Look for the part about using the "login:ci" command of the CLI.  The Firebase CLI documentation has more detail about it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems

Comment: thanks for all your help. I was trying to avoid following procedure without understanding what it is doing. What is the best place for me to understand FB tokens? Also, I did `login:ci`, it asked for my google account, then asked for permissions, then redirected me to `http://localhost:9005/....`! Obviously I don't have any server on that port so I got an error. (I'm testing my code via `python -m http.serve` on port 8000). Even `firebase serve` seem to serve port 5000.

Comment: Adding '--no-localhost' seems to solve that problem. Unlike programming, I think I need to read the deployment docs fully before making any headway!

Answer (score 2):

The token is a login token used to login to your account on a server to get permission to execute the command as if you were doing it using the Firebase CLI. You only need to generate it once and deploy it.

As of `firebase-functions v3.18.0`, it's recommended to use the dotenv format to store your variables. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#env-variables

##### Steps:

1. Run `firebase login:ci` in the command line
2. Create a `.env` file in `functions/`
3. Put the line `TOKEN=<your_token_from_step_1>`
4. Use it like so:

> ```
> await firebase_tools.firestore.delete(path, {
>               project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
>               recursive: true,
>               yes: true,
>               force: true
>               token: process.env.TOKEN, // Like this
>             });
> ```

5. Run `firebase deploy --only functions`

Note: I added `force: true` because of [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932654/firebase-functions-firebaseerror-missing-required-options-force-while-runni).